# How to speed up for loop?

Tags: python, for-loop, optimization

I am trying to speed up this for loop in python, where N is a large number around 12000. This loop takes over 20 seconds to run. The lines calculating cossum and sinsum seem to be the main culprits here. How can I optimise this so it runs faster?

(I am pretty new to coding so a simple explanation would be very appreciated! Thanks)

```
for i in range(N): 

    cossum = 0
    sinsum = 0

    sq = k_array[i][0]**2 + k_array[i][1]**2 + k_array[i][2]**2
   
    if sq <= sqmax and sq>0:

        kvec_used = kvec_used + 1
        kfac[i] = np.exp(-sq/(4*beta**2))/(sq)
    
        for j in range(sites):
            cossum = cossum + q_array_initial[j]*np.cos(np.dot(k_array[i],r_cart_initial[j]))
            sinsum = sinsum + q_array_initial[j]*np.sin(np.dot(k_array[i],r_cart_initial[j]))

            cos_part = (abs(cossum))**2
            sin_part = (abs(sinsum))**2
```

Comment: As a suggestion, you can try using the `time` module to determine which part of your loop is taking the longest time on average. Then, try to optimize the code in those blocks (for example, see if the problem is the `cossum` and `sinsum`. As it stands right now, this question is very broad.

Comment: Thanks, I did this and found the majority of the time (around 19 seconds) was spent calculating cossum and sinsum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove all of the `for` loops in your code using vectorization in Numpy.  I recommend reading [Look Ma No For Loops](https://realpython.com/numpy-array-programming/) as you start venturing down this path.

I took your example and generated some junk data to stand in for your arrays and variables using `random`.

```
import numpy as np
import random
import time

kvec_used = 0
k_array = []
sqmax = 10
beta = .5
kfac = []
sites = 3
q_array_initial = r_cart_initial = [.1, .2, .3]

for i in range(12000):
    temp = [random.random(), random.random(), random.random()]
    k_array.append(temp)
    kfac.append(random.random())

mytime = time.time()
for i in range(12000): 
    cossum = 0
    sinsum = 0

    sq = k_array[i][0]**2 + k_array[i][1]**2 + k_array[i][2]**2

    if sq <= sqmax and sq>0:

        kvec_used = kvec_used + 1
        kfac[i] = np.exp(-sq/(4*beta**2))/(sq)
    
        for j in range(sites):
            cossum = cossum + q_array_initial[j]*np.cos(np.dot(k_array[i],r_cart_initial[j]))
            sinsum = sinsum + q_array_initial[j]*np.sin(np.dot(k_array[i],r_cart_initial[j]))

            cos_part = (abs(cossum))**2
            sin_part = (abs(sinsum))**2

print("looped", time.time() - mytime)


mytime = time.time()

k_array = np.asarray(k_array)
sq = np.square(k_array[:, 0]) + np.square(k_array[:, 1]) + np.square(k_array[:, 2])
sq = sq[np.where(np.logical_and(sq[:] <= sqmax, sq[:] > 0))]
kvec = np.shape(sq)[0]
kfac = np.exp(-sq[:]/(4*beta**2))/(sq[:])

for j in range(sites):
    cossum = cossum + q_array_initial[j]*np.cos(np.dot(k_array[i],r_cart_initial[j]))
    sinsum = sinsum + q_array_initial[j]*np.sin(np.dot(k_array[i],r_cart_initial[j]))

    cos_part = (abs(cossum))**2
    sin_part = (abs(sinsum))**2

print("vectorized:", time.time() - mytime)
```

By only vectorizing the first for loop, I get a speed up of ~100 times when I measure using `time.time()`.  On my machine, the output of this code is:

```sh
looped 0.40552735328674316
vectorized: 0.004940986633300781
```

You should be able to speed up even more when you vectorize the second loop.

---

Edit: I just realized you asked for more explanation in your original question.  The article I linked above explains things in detail and is what I used when I first started vectorizing large data sets.  However, I can offer a super-simple explanation to get you going here:

When you have a large array, it is actually a bit slow in Python to run a `for` loop.  Numpy uses some more advanced code behind-the-scenes which can run operations more quickly than you can sequentially in a `for` loop.  For the purposes of a novice learning this, you can accept that Numpy is "magic" for the time being.  The big take away here is that rather than going through and operating on the `i`th element of your array, you want to tell Numpy to operate on the whole thing, represented as `myarray[:]`.  You can extend this out to multidimensional arrays.  A full 2D array is `myarray[:, :]`.  If (thinking in spreadsheet terms) you just want to operate on the 0th column and all rows on a 2d array, this becomes `myarray[:, 0]`.

Here, I have used fancy Numpy-specific methods `where` and `logical_and` to replace your `if` conditional.  This is another vectorization technique which is able to handle conditional statements more quickly than an iterative approach.

I purposely left the second `for` loop untranslated as an exercise for you.  No one learns without suffering!  You have done good to use `np.cos` and `np.sin` here, but you use them in an iterative way.  Use the vector approach to run these math operators on all elements of the result vector.

Comment: great motivated example of vectorization, backed with a good reference. +1 for you good sir

Comment: Thanks- really great explanation! I'm attempting the second ```for``` loop. I tried to use [:] for both ```k_array```  (after doing ```k_array = k_array[np.where...]```) and ```r_cart_initial``` but they are different dimensions so it does not work. I then made a list of combinations of the indices of ```k_array``` and of  ```r_cart_initial``` however I'm baffled as to how to avoid a loop. Any hints?

Comment: The ``k_array[np.where...]`` step actually removes the rows which produce incorrect results, which will change the size of the array.  Perhaps try reversing the logic so that the incorrect values are replaced with ``n/a`` rather than removed.  Also, I assume that ``q_array_initial`` is a different size than ``k_array``.  In that case, you will want to look at ways to broadcast differently shaped arrays.

Comment: ```k_array``` is a different size to both ```q_array_initial``` and ```r_cart_initial```, Will broadcasting allow me to consider all combinations of ```k_array``` and the other arrays? –

Comment: Yes, but you should "cheat" a bit by creating a new arrays of equivalent sizes in one dimension by repeating rows.  E.g. for 1D arrays like``A = [[0, 1]]`` and ``B = [[3, 4, 5]]``, make new arrays using numpy repeat/tile and friends which end up looking like ``AA = [[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]]`` and ``BB = [[3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5]]``.